# Why does Interstitial Ads return me back to the home page?

Tags: java, android

I've made an **webview app**. I added interstitial ad on a regular interval. suppose after **120 seconds**. When I close the interstitial Ad it take me back to the home page. Suppose I am browsing ABOUT Page. After close the ad it takes me back to the home page. But I want to stay in ABOUT  page.

Main Activity.Java

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    prepareAd();
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("Sample", "CV");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", " Interstitial not loaded");
                    }
                    prepareAd();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 20, 40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
public void prepareAd() {
```

Comment: How do you close the ad?

Comment: On back Press or Just simply click the cross symbol to close the add.